# 100% fixed div with overflow in child-div & fixed height heading

Tags: css

I am looking to create a popup box, which I've done by way of a fixed div positioned 5% in.

I want it to fill the entire viewable window with the 5% border around the edge.

Currently (I've only viewed in Chrome), I can achieve the layout I want, but there is no gap at the bottom because if the body of text div has a height, it adds on the height of the header.

I've tried all sorts, from adding it into another containing div and plonking height: 100% all over the show, to no avail.

http://jsfiddle.net/VukSZ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the targeted [browser support](http://caniuse.com/calc), you can use the CSS [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc) function. Just set the height of your `#popup_body` to `calc(100% - 40px);` (you'll have to include multiple versions with different vendor-specific prefixes).

Here's a modified version of your demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/fBVtM/).

If you need to support older browsers, you have to use JavaScript.